# Calculating generating functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have been asked to give generating functions for
$$(1)\;\;\; f(n) = 3^{n}$$
$$(2)\;\;\; g(n) = 3$$
$$(3)\;\;\; h(n) = 3n $$

I understand a generating function can be written such as
$$\langle 1, 1, 1, 1, ...\rangle = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} ... = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

In terms of relating this to an expression such as those on the RHS of the questions, I have no idea. If the generating function example I gave were the answer, what would $f(n)$ be equal to in the question (or would it be $f(x)$)?

The answers are
$$(1)\;\;\; \dfrac{1}{1-3x} $$
$$(2)\;\;\; \dfrac{3}{1-x} $$
$$(3)\;\;\; \dfrac{3x}{(1-x)^{2}} $$

If anyone could explain how these are obtained, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the terms of a sequence are coefficients of a power series.

Answer (score 1):

Generating functions for coefficients $a(n)$, $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ are defined as

$$G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n) x^n.$$

So for your examples

(1):
\begin{align}
G(x) & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) x^n \\
     & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^n x^n \\
   & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty (3x)^n \\
    & =  \frac{1}{1-3x}
\end{align}
by the geometric sum;

(2):
\begin{align}
G(x) & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) x^n \\
     & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3 x^n \\
   & =  3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \\
    & =  \frac{3}{1-x}
\end{align}
also by the geometric sum;

and
(3):
\begin{align}
G(x) & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty h(n) x^n \\
     & =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3n x^n \\
   & =  3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n \\
   & =  3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} x^n \\
& =  \frac{d}{dx} \frac{3}{1-x} \\
    & =  \frac{3x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
again by the geometric sum. We can exchange derivative and sum due to the uniform convergence of the geometric sum.